# Can I use comparative adjective for compound adjectives

Tags: comparative-constructions

Can I use comparative adjective  for compound adjectives?

For example,

> Caged birds are longer-lived birds than the ones in the wild.

Comment: What compound adjective? longer-lived is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  You can say

> Caged birds are longer-lived than birds in the wild.